# How to strip away and get rid of (... days, 0:00:00) from a value acquired from a date calculation

Tags: web2py

I have 4 values that have to be calculated together to set a default value for the fifth value, 2 of the 4 values are date values but the problem is that calculating their difference leaves **days, 0:00:00** as part of the answer but i only want the value number they give, is there a way to strip away the **days, 0:00:00** from the date calculation answer so i could use the remaining value in my calculation and get the answer i want?

**Example Code**

**MODEL:**

```
db.define_table('hotels',
            Field('Hotel'),
            Field('Bookin', 'date'),
            Field('Bookout', 'date'),
            Field('days', compute=lambda r: r['Bookout']-r['Bookin']),
            Field('guests', 'integer'),
            Field('price', compute=lambda r: r['days']*r['guests']*650))
```

Answer (score 0):

I could always add (**.days**) in the days field as illustrated [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/web2py/p7E5Z5Yr2aw) by **sandeep patel**